# Kafka cluster fail handling explanation

Tags: apache-kafka, bigdata

I would like to set up an apache kafka cluster for using it in a new project. Unfortunately I can't find any detailed explanation on how kafka handle broker fails and network partitioning.
For example, if I have a cluster made of 2 or more brokers and 1 node fail, does the only one node up keep accepting messages?
If yes, when the second come up again, how it resync its missing data?

Comment: Hi, be warned that (although I wish everyone asked themselves this sort of question before choosing a product) this isn't really a programming problem, more an infrastructure one, so it's unlikely to fit the StackOverflow community's remit.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#replication) and [here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#design_replicatedlog) at the description of the replication protocol that Kafka uses. Each partition in a Kafka topic has a 'leader', and messages are sent to the leader. Messages are replicated to 'followers'.

So to answer you questions specifically, my understanding is:

> if I have a cluster made of 2 or more brokers and 1 node fail, does the only one node up keep accepting messages?

Only one node accepts messages anyway; the leader node. If a follower fails, the leader continues to accept messages. 
If the leader fails a new leader is elected from those followers that are up to date.

> If yes, when the second come up again, how it resync its missing data?

'Followers' act as consumers of the 'leader', so a follower once brought back up will continue to consume its messages from the leader to get back into sync.